# Saving Javadoc across runs

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

How can I save the build path for a project so I don't have to import the Javadocs every time I start eclipse? Right now I have to import the Javadoc for every external library I have in the project.

Answer (score 0):

It's a weird behavior, the class files should know where the javadoc is after you added it for the first time.

Are you using a simple Java project? What you could do is make a `lib` folder in your project, copy the JARs and source there, and then add them to the build path.

As much as possible , try **avoiding external dependencies**. You never know when they'll just be gone from where they were.